# Converting sql to eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a self join in eloquent, here it is in SQL

```
SELECT t2.id FROM products t1, products t2 
WHERE t1.id = 1 
AND t2.id != 1
AND (t1.color_id = t2.color_id
OR t1.process_id = t2.process_id
OR t1.length_id = t2.length_id
OR t1.size_id = t2.size_id 
OR t1.height_id = t2.height_id)
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
```

Here is what I have in eloquent:

```
Product::join('products AS t2', 'products.id', '=', 't2.id')
    ->select('t2.id')
    ->where('products.id', 1)
    ->where('t2.id', '!=', 1)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('products.color_id', '=', 't2.color_id')
        ->orWhere('products.process_id', '=', 't2.process_id')
        ->orWhere('products.length_id', '=', 't2.length_id')
        ->orWhere('products.size_id', '=', 't2.size_id')
        ->orWhere('products.height_id', '=', 't2.height_id');
      })
    ->get();
```

I have yet to add order by and limit to eloquent - just trying to get some results out first.

The problem with the eloquent is that it's producing 0 results, where my sql does give me the results I expect, where am I going wrong?

### Edit

I have modified my query to:

```
Product::join('products AS t2', 'products.id', '=', 't2.id')
->select('t2.id')
->where(function($query){
    $query->where('products.color_id', '=', 't2.color_id')
    ->orWhere('products.process_id', '=', 't2.process_id')
    ->orWhere('products.length_id', '=', 't2.length_id')
    ->orWhere('products.size_id', '=', 't2.size_id')
    ->orWhere('products.height_id', '=', 't2.height_id');
  })
->get();
```

But still 0 results.

### Edit 2

Here is the sql statement being run:

```
select 
    `t2`.`id` 
from 
    `products` inner join `products` as `t2` 
on 
    `products`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
where (
    `products`.`look_color_id` = ? or 
    `products`.`process_id` = ? or 
    `products`.`length_id` = ? or
    `products`.`size_id` = ? or 
    `products`.`height_id` = ?
)
```

Comment: I make some typo in queries, Laravel writes whole query and then I debug it :). Problem is in `->where('products.id', 1)`, where you forgot equal sign, I think.

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work.

Comment: And another problem is in join, because you join `p.id = t.id` and then write condition like this `p.id = 1 and t.id <> 1` which is always false and in your original query you do not have this join. So look for joining two same tables.

Comment: @Jzef Duc it is not compulsory to put equal sign in where condition in Laravel. It's optional :)

Comment: @Michel yes, I know, but it was not main goal of a comment :)

Comment: I still can't get my query to work, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Get the last query: `$queries = DB::getQueryLog(); echo end($queries);` that should help you out.

Comment: Thanks, Ive looked at the log but still cant figure it out.

Comment: The problem can be in join with two opposite conditions as I wrote before.

Comment: Yes I have taken that out, still no results.

Comment: What query do you get from @DavidNguyen comment?

Comment: Updated question with sql output

Comment: Now you can see an error. Use `orWhereRaw` instead of `where` so for example `->orWhereRaw('products.height_id = t2.height_id')`. More informations here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Thanks I then get the error "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"

Comment: I've just seen your updated comment, Ive updated my nested wheres to be orWhereRaw and I get the error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWhereRaw() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Never mind solved that, now i get the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.color_id = t2.color_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thanks, I have now solved the issue and data is coming out, although its the wrong data. So the query is not th equivalent of my original sql query.